# Submitting a package to CRAN does not accept set.seed inside a function but do not know how to avoid it

Tags: r, montecarlo, cran, random-seed

I am submitting a package to CRAN, that identifies breaks in a time series, for this in some functions of the package I do Montecarlo simulations. In order to guarantee same result for the same input from the functions that perform Montecarlo simulations, I set a seed inside the function. The CRAN moderator tall me: "Please do not set a seed to a specific number within a function."

The problem is how to achieve same result with the same input if no seed is set. Here is an example to understand the problem, in which `function2`  set a seed inside and the result is always equal compare `max2`  and `max4`, instead `funtion1`  does the same but does not set seed and the result varies.

```
x <- c(1:100)

#Function without set.seed
function1 <- function(x,simulations = 100){

  mn <- mean(x)
  sd <- sd(x)
  max_vect <- vector(mode = 'double',length = simulations)
  for(i in 1:simulations){
    x_aux <- rnorm(n = length(x),mean = mn,sd = sd)

    max_vect[i] <- max(x_aux)

  }

  return(mean(max_vect))
}

#Function that set.seed
function2 <- function(x,simulations = 100){

  mn <- mean(x)
  sd <- sd(x)
  max_vect <- vector(mode = 'double',length = simulations)
  set.seed(1234)
  for(i in 1:simulations){
    x_aux <- rnorm(n = length(x),mean = mn,sd = sd)

    max_vect[i] <- max(x_aux)

  }

  return(mean(max_vect))
}

max1 <- function1(x)
max2 <- function2(x)

max3 <- function1(x)
max4 <- function2(x)
```

Comment: I suggest you don't hard-code `set.seed` inside functions, be them in a package or not. Write the function like `function1` and let the ***user*** set the RNG seed before calling the function. In `function2` you are deciding what seed users are forced to use. Users ***must*** have the freedom to make their results reproducible.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that, but I want to make user-friendly functions to users that do not know much programming. Maybe considering what you say, I can add an argument to the function to specify if the seed must be set or not.

Comment: So a user that does not know about setting seed, use the default argument and seed is set inside the function, but a user that wants to set it before can do it too.

Comment: OK, or an argument `seed` with a default value of `NULL` that users can change at will. This value would be tested by the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with comments. Do this

```
myFunction <-function (x, y,z, seed = NULL) {
if (length(seed) ) set.seed(seed)
# the function guts
}
```